# create an associative array with multiple values to one key in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key, associative

I want to dynamically create an associative array where we can assign multiple values to one key in php.
That is each key behaves itself as an array.
Eg

```
$array=[$one->'1','2','3';
    $two->'4','5';
    $three->'1']
```

I will dynamically receive values for every key in a loop, so i cannot initialise the entire array statically.Please give the entire php code for this.

Comment: there are examples at the php docs. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `$array=[$one=>['1','2','3'],
    $two=>['4','5'],
    $three=>['1']];`

Comment: @MarkBaker: i cannot initialise the array as i will dynamically receive values for every key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you create an array of arrays?

```
$array = array();
$array[1] = array();
$array[2] = array();
$array[3] = array();
array_push($array[1],1);
array_push($array[1],2);
array_push($array[1],3);
array_push($array[2],4);
array_push($array[2],5);
array_push($array[3],6);
```

You will be able to add as many as you like, and create new fields when needed.
In general though you will have to give you variable names more meaningful than just $array :)